# How to set status image in SharePoint Online (365) column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I would like to show status icon as a picture in my list in column called "ICON" in SharePoint 365. I am using calculated column to show the icon, a picture which is stored in the Site Assets library in SharePoint.

I followed several guidance, I am able to display one icon for all rows if I use following formula:

```
 ="<DIV><img src='https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/Premier%20Oil%20-%20Vendor%20Neutral%20Service/SiteAssets/227-rect_red.png'
 & IF([Overall Status]=(3) Red) '></DIV>"
```

But I cant work out how to display the right icon when selecting the Overall Status, which is either Green, Amber or Red, I am using following formula, but receiving errors.

```
 ="<DIV><img src='" & IF([Overall Status]=(3) Red, "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/Premier%20Oil%20-%20Vendor%20Neutral%20Service/SiteAssets/227-rect_red.png",
 IF([Overall Status]=(2) Amber,
 "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/Premier%20Oil%20-%20Vendor%20Neutral%20Service/SiteAssets/241-triang_yellow.png",
 IF([Overall Status]=(1) Green,
 "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/Premier%20Oil%20-%20Vendor%20Neutral%20Service/SiteAssets/228-rect_green.png")))
 & "'></DIV>"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Remember: Microsoft disabled HTML in Calculation Columns for SPOnline in june 2017**

---

You missed a lot of quotes or used the wrong ones.

**always** edit Formulas in Notepad or another TextEditor and use plenty of linebreaks and tabs; they will be ignored when you paste/save the Formula in a SharePoint column.

*I did not test this formula, could be typos left*

```
="<IMG src='"
&"https://fesl.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/Premier%20Oil%20-%20Vendor%20Neutral%20Service/SiteAssets/"
    &IF([Overall Status]="(3) Red"
        ,"227-rect_red.png"
        ,IF([Overall Status]="(2) Amber"
            ,"241-triang_yellow.png"
            ,IF([Overall Status]="(1) Green"
                , "228-rect_green.png"
                )
            )
        )
    & "'>"
```

Note: To format code in a StackOverflow post use 4 spaces or the " button from the buttonbar when posting code/formulas in StackOverflow

More Formula help at:
http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: Many thanks Danny, the formula works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: Don't forget... **always** work from a text-editor with Formulas. And mark questions answered so StackOverflow can rate correct answers. More Formula help at: http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: I tried this solution in SharePoint online today and it just shows the code right on the page, rather than rendering the picture.

Comment: That's why the top of the message refers to Microsoft disabling it in 2017